# use ORDER BY to these term queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

right i have two queries that scan a MYSQL database for keywords and return them whether they are a) Together or b) separate. I now added a new column called 'rank', which ranks them in order. I added 'ORDER BY rank' to each query and when i type in a single term, the results are displayed correctly, but when two terms or more are entered I get this error: MySQL Query Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY rank' at line 1.
  The results are automatically ranked by id. When i removed an ORDER BY tag, from just one query, the other query's tag won't work. I don't get it? My queries are below.

```
    // Terms Together
    $query = " SELECT * FROM scan WHERE "; 

$terms = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $terms);
$i = 0; 
foreach ($terms as $each) {
      if ($i++ !== 0){
            $query .= " AND ";
      }
      $query .= "keywords LIKE '%{$each}%' ORDER BY rank";
}

            /* Query Statement Building - Terms Separate */
    $query = " SELECT * FROM scan WHERE "; 

    $terms = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $terms);
    $i = 0; 
    foreach ($terms as $each) {
          if ($i++ !== 0){
                $query .= " OR "; 
          }
          $query .= "keywords LIKE '%{$each}%' ORDER BY rank";
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

The `ORDER BY` must come at the end of the loop, not inside the loop. Otherwise you get multiple `ORDER BY` statements per query, which is invalid:

```
foreach ($terms as $each) {
      if ($i++ !== 0){
            $query .= " OR "; 
      }
      $query .= "keywords LIKE '%{$each}%'";
}
// Don't append the ORDER BY until after the loop
$query .= " ORDER BY rank";
```

Change *both* of your loops to use this pattern instead of what you currently have.